# Python CSV: NoneType error while reading file

Tags: python, csv, indexing, while-loop, typeerror

My code is returning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Justin/Desktop/Program 5/Weather_Program#5.py", line 55, in <module>
    if date[0:] == None:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I know exactly where and why this error is occurring, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

The data I'm reading in the `csv` is dates in left column and precipitation in right column. `20000101` would be january 1st 2001 and 0 would be 0 inches of rain.

```
20000101    0

20000102    0

20000103    0

20000104    0.3
```

code:

```
import csv

january   = []
february  = []
march     = []
april     = []
may       = []
june      = []
july      = []
august    = []
september = []
october   = []
november  = []
december  = []

def read_cell(column, row):
    """Input x & y coordinate for CSV file: Returns information in cell"""
    with open('precipitation.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        y_count = 0
        for n in reader:
            if y_count == row:
                cell = n[column]
                return cell
            y_count += 1

stormy = 0
row_number = 0

while stormy < 1:
    with open('precipitation.csv', 'r') as f:
            date = read_cell(0,row_number)
            rain = read_cell(1,row_number)

            if date[0:] == None:
                stormy += 1
                break

            elif date[4:6] == "01":
                january.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1                

            elif date[4:6] == "02":
                february.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "03":
                march.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "04":
                april.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "05":
                may.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == "06":
                june.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == "07":
                july.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == "08":
                august.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == '09':
                september.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == '10':
                october.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               

            elif date[4:6] == '11':
                november.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1

            elif date[4:6] == '12':
                december.append(read_cell(1,row_number))
                row_number += 1               


print(january)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only stop condition on the `while` loop is `if date[0:] == None`. That means your loop will continue until at some point the file doesn't have another line, at which point `date` and `rain` will be set to `None`. At that point, in the stop condition, you're trying to do `None[0:]` which is what's throwing an error.

Try `if date == None` instead.

Comment: If it fixed your problem please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that the problem may be in the input file?
Other possibilities: the leading zero in the months may be the issue.

Would you consider using a panda's dataframe? the you could filter to get the month and store those monthly results into a dataframe for each month

CSV file are faily easy to import into a dataframe. If you need more help, i will give it

Comment: The problem occurs when the program iterates through the file and hits an empty cell at the end.

I have been coding for about 4 months now and have never used a panda's dataframe. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: import pandas as pd                                                                                import df = pd.read_csv('precipitation.csv')
print df

Answer (score 0):

1. You're opening the CSV twice
2. Everytime you read a cell, you're rescanning the whole CSV file
3. The exception at line 55 does match your source code
4. You're not handling blank lines/cells. At the top of your while loop you need:

   ```
   if date is None:
       continue
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From my workings with csv files the open needs to be

import csv

with open('names.csv',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile: ...
 reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) ... 
   for row in reader:
It maybe your decoding

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), it looks like the default delimiter is a comma.  Your code didn't work for me until I opened the reader like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
```

(This assumes those are tabs in the CSV file.  If they are spaces, then the delimiter needs to be `delimiter=' '`, which is more difficult because then the results will end up in column 4).

Also I agree that you should check `if date is None`.  However I think you should also explicitly return `None` at the end of `read_cell()`, since that is where it is coming from.

One more thing: It looks like from your question that the CSV file is double-spaced.  This didn't work for me -- the for loop stopped after the first line instead of looping through the whole file.  In my test I changed it to single-spaced because maybe that is what the actual file is.